# How to calculate the trace of $ad(H)$ as a linear operator acting on $\mathfrak{g}_{n\alpha}$?

Tags: lie-algebras, root-systems

The convention is set as follows: we have a semi-simple complex Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{h}\oplus\bigoplus_\alpha\mathfrak{g}_\alpha$ as its root space decomposition. If $\alpha\notin\Delta$, where $\Delta$ is the set of roots, then $\mathfrak{g}_\alpha=\{0\}$. For any root $\alpha\in\Delta$, denote $H_\alpha\in\mathfrak{h}$ such that $\alpha(H)=\mathcal{K}(H,H_\alpha)$. We know that $H_\alpha=[E_\alpha,E_{-\alpha}]$ therefore Tr$(ad(H_\alpha))=0$ as a linear operator on $\mathfrak{g}$. For any integer $n$, the subspace $\bigoplus_n\mathfrak{g}_{n\alpha}$ is invariant under the action of $ad(H_\alpha)$ and we conclude $Tr(ad(H_\alpha))=0$ on $
\bigoplus_n\mathfrak{g}_{n\alpha}$.

From Lie's theorem we know that there exists a basis in $\mathfrak{g}_{n\alpha}$ such that $ad(H_\alpha)$ is upper-triangular and we can denote the first element of that basis as $E_{n\alpha}$ such that $ad(H_\alpha)E_{n\alpha}=n\alpha(H_\alpha)E_{n\alpha}$. We therefore could obtain the first addition term in the formula of Tr$(ad(H_\alpha))$ for each $\mathfrak{g}_{n\alpha}$.

What I fail to understand is why we could conclude that Tr($ad(H_\alpha)$)=$\sum_nn\alpha(H_\alpha)\dim\mathfrak{g}_{n\alpha}$. It would be extremely helpful if someone could offer or point me to an explanation.

Comment: But out of $n\alpha$ only $\alpha$ and $-\alpha$ are actually roots. Additionally the trace of $\mathrm{ad}(X)$ will always be zero for any $X\in \mathfrak{g}$ in more generality. If you really only want to prove it for a specific coroot the only thing you need is that for every root $\beta$, $-\beta$ is also a root and the eigenvalues of $H_\alpha$ on $\mathfrak{g}_\beta$ and $\mathfrak{g}_{-\beta}$ are negatives of each other. So whatever the eigenvalues are they must add up to 0.

Comment: @Callum Hi Callum, this is in the middle of proving that the only roots of $\mathbb{Z}\alpha$, given $\alpha$ a root, are $\alpha$ and $-\alpha$. All I am allowed to know is the definition of $\mathfrak{g}_{n\alpha}=\{g\in\mathfrak{g}|\exists s\in\mathbb{N}~(ad(H)-n\alpha(H))^sg=0\}$, and Lie's theorem and killing forms.

Comment: $ad(H_\alpha)$ restricted to $\mathfrak g_{n\alpha}$ can be written as upper triangular matrix with *each* diagonal entry being $n\alpha(H)$. That immediately implies your assertion.